# AWS CLI and jq : Error when fetching Task ID using ecs list-tasks

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to fetch the Task ID from the list-tasks response using jq, and am running into an error.

```
[Container] 2020/07/17 02:20:27 Running command aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME
{
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:420785284875:task/f6a58bda-d564-4213-8ac9-bccb82244f16"
    ]
}

[Container] 2020/07/17 02:20:27 Running command TASK_ID=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME |  jq .taskArns|.[0])
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 4: .[0]: command not found

[Container] 2020/07/17 02:20:28 Command did not exit successfully TASK_ID=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME |  jq .taskArns|.[0]) exit status 127
[Container] 2020/07/17 02:20:28 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/07/17 02:20:28 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: TASK_ID=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME |  jq .taskArns|.[0]). Reason: exit status 127
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

### I was able to resolve that ..

```
 TASK_ID=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME |  jq .taskArns[0])
```

and then

```
echo "Task ID is $TASK_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `aws-cli` query parameter then one should use `jq`?

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster demo --region us-west-2 --query "taskArns" --output text
```